# Parse Saving Objects from For In loop Issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform, swift2

I'm having an issue saving my objects to the Parse object I created. I have Strings in a `UITableview` that the user uses a `UISwitch`to indicate they want to save the String. Once everything the user has selected what they want they push the save button on the `UIToolbar` just below the table. Once the save button is activated two checks are made: The first is to ensure the `UISwitch`has been turned on the next is to check the contents of the `NSDictionary` that contains the strings. I have put in checks to ensure the `for in loop` is reading the values from the dictionary properly and it is. But the the only object being saved is the last object being ran through the `for in loop`. Not sure why. Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func questionSaved(sender: AnyObject){


    for (key,value) in savedItems{

        if key == cellNumber && value == true{

            for (key,value) in physicalQuestions{

                questionStore["physicalQuestion"] = value

                questionStore.saveInBackgroundWithBlock{ (success, error) -> Void in


                    //Set Deleted Value to False when Succeeded
                    if (success){

                        self.questionStore["deleted"] = false
                        self.questionStore.saveInBackground()


                    }else{

                        self.questionStore["deleted"] = true
                        self.questionStore.saveInBackground()
                    }


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help I really appreciate it.

Comment: You only seem to have a single `questionStore` item that you are updating repeatedly, so the last value saved will be the last value that you see in Parse for that object

Comment: @Paulw11 cellNumber is set from `cell.mySwitch.tag = indexPath.row` and then `cellNumber = mySwitch.tag` so it saves the appropriate values and I verified that multiple `String` values are getting run through the loop by `print(value)`. Each time the loop get run a different value comes up but only the last value run through the loop gets saved.

Comment: Yes, I revised my comment; your problem is that you are repeatedly updating a single Parse object (`questionStore`) so only the final values of that object will be persisted in the store

Comment: Okay I was thinking about that when I was writing my question initially. I guess this confirms my suspicion that the Parse acts like a `NSDictionary` correct? Should I have some way to `i++` through the values so they all save? Any thoughts on that?

Comment: A Parse object is a little like a dictionary in the way you can access its properties, but more importantly each "row" in the Parse object table is a different object, a different dictionary if you like.  I don't know how you have structured your data on Parse; do you want to have a single object with an array of data (questions?) or do you want multiple objects?  I suspect the latter, in which case you need to get the appropriate PFObject reference and update it

Comment: Loop changes value too fast than asyncronous works. Look at the Promise's patterns at docs.

Comment: @GPack This is nothing to do with asynchronous execution or execution speed.  It is the fact that a single PFObject is being updated, overwriting previous values, so only the final values will be written at the completion of the loop

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for the help on this the last explanation makes sense about the PFObject. I will see what I come up with thanks again.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm trying to retrieve my objectId like this `let questionId = questionStore.objectId` and then pass the `questionId` into the `query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(questionId!)` declaration but I keep getting nil and after the app crashes. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: You rarely need to use object Ids.  You can just retrieve the PFObject from Parse and pass the reference around in your app.  You can then call `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` or whatever to save it after you update it.

Comment: @Paulw11 But I need the objectId to retrieve the the PFObject and I was trying to make the retrieval dynamic so the app will retrieve unique values if necessary. Is this possible to process the data as I wrote above?

Comment: In order to get the object id you need to retrieve the object and if you have retrieved the object already, just hang on to it.

Comment: @Paulw11 Got It Thanks man.